# Deploying Tensorflow app on the customer's infra

Tags: python, c++, deployment, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm currently developing a prediction model using Tensorflow and my model works well  for a customer, so I'm tring to make it as a real product.

My model needs to be retrained using customer's input as time passes, and it should be deployed on customers infrastructure. (Not a SaaS or cloud.) Moreover, I'd like to protect my codes and models.

From my understanding of Tensorflow, trained model can be exported as protobuf, freezed and kept nodes that are required by prediction. [freeze_graph.py at Tensorflow repo,](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py) I tried it and I successfully ran my prediction model using Golang + libtensorflow.so runtime. (Or, I could use Tensorflow Serving & C++)

If I can train my model on our company's infra, I could say "Okay, let's get some beers". However, my model has to be trained on the customer's infra, and without python code, it seems like I cannot train my model.

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/how_tos/language_bindings/index.html

> At this time, support for gradients, functions and control flow operations ("if" and "while") is not available in languages other than Python. This will be updated when the C API provides necessary support.

Is there any workaround deploying TF app without exposing python code or model? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Won't obfuscation be enough?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use Python with a pre-trained model, without exposing all the code you needed to build it in the first place. As an example of this, have a look at the Inception retraining code, which loads a pretrained GraphDef and then retrains a new top layer:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py

Comment: No, it can't hide my model (GraphDef protobuf). Even I encrypt model's protobuf, I need to decrypt on Python code in order to train it.